# How to mask a URL on a different port with htaccess rewrite

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page with a URL like this:

```
https://example.com:3000/newsite
```

but I want to be able to access it from here:

```
https://example.com/newsite
```

and mask the URL as well so it will always show everything like this before the last `/`

I tried like this:

```
RewriteRule ^:3000/newsite/?$ /site/
```

but it didn't work. Why?

My whole `.htaccess` looks like this because I have already some other rules that have to stay the same:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]           <---everything up to this point has to stay the same

RewriteRule ^:3000/newchat/?$ /chat/
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^:3000/newsite/?$ /site/
> ```

You can't simply "remove" the port number from the requested URL in this way (with an internal rewrite).

To do as you are asking would require you to configure a reverse-proxy (which likely requires changes to the server config), but you still need to actually change the URLs on your site to remove the port number from all internal links.

However, in order to configure the reverse proxy (from port 443(HTTPS) to port 3000 on which the site is actually running), you would need to configure the server to *listen* on and accept requests to port 443 (and port 80(HTTP) to redirect to port 443(HTTPS)).

But if you have access to the server on which to configure all the above then why not just serve the content on the standard port(s) (ie. 443) directly? (Which begs the question, why port 3000 was being used to begin with?)